# Angular js with codeigniter

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter

I want to show data in a table with angular js. I have tried many code but didn't solve my problem. Please help

Here is my code of **View** page..

**Script code**

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller("customersCtrl", function($scope, $http) {   
    $http.get('<?php echo base_url('items/getRecords'); ?>').
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {       
    $scope.users = data;
});
 });
</script>
```

**HTML Code**

```
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">                
            <table class="datatable table table-striped table-bordered" id="example">
                <thead>
                    <tr>                    
                        <th>Product Code</th>                       
                        <th>Product Name</th>                           
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                    <tr class="gradeA" ng-repeat="x in users">

                        <td style="text-align:center;">{{x.item_code}}</td>                         
                        <td style="text-align:center;">{{x.item_name}}</td>         

                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>
```

**On Controller**

```
 public function getRecords(){

    $this->load->model('item_model');
    $data=$this->item_model->getTransactionData();
    $this->output->set_header('Content-type: application/json');
    $this->output->set_output(json_encode($data));
}
```

And finally on **Model**

```
public function getTransactionData(){


    $query=$this->db->get('ac_itrans');
    return $query->result();

}
```

Here is Json format of my result:

```
  [{"itrans_id":"17","cocode":"OFLT","yearcode":"OFLT16","vseries":"S","vnum":"1","vdate":"2015-10-06","linenum":"1","item_type":"services","item_code":"26","item_name":"AC Repair"}];
```

Console log

[image]

Comment: So what doesn't work?

Comment: Does GET request return anything?

Comment: yeah, when i alert(data.length) in success, its returns 17

Comment: Check the error in console.

Comment: There is no any error in console

Comment: Kindly Enclose URL returned by base_url('items/getRecords') properly.

Comment: Well your code is okay. It means that it's something specific to your app which we can't see here. For example you will not be able to reproduce the issue in demo, because code is okay. So just debug your app :)

Comment: @JayKandari my base_url('items/getRecords') is correct

Comment: $http.get('<?php echo base_url('items/getRecords'); ?>').

See Single quotes.. plus no Concatenation. either wrap whole <?php ?> inside double quotes

Answer (score 0):

please read tutorial from [here](http://www.tamtech.co.in/angularjs-with-codeigniter-php-framework), there is good way to do integrate angularjs with codeigniter php framework.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, code is correct.

you need to debug to check whether you are getting right JSON format. check this using console.log($scope.user)..instead of data.length.

use devtool to see what it returns. Put that snapshot here.

and don't you need to initialize the user !

```
 $scope.user = [];
```

Comment: [{"itrans_id":"17","cocode":"OFLT","yearcode":"OFLT16","vseries":"S","vnum":"1","vdate":"2015-10-06","linenum":"1","item_type":"services","item_code":"26","item_name":"AC Repair"}];

Comment: can you tell what does this return !! empty field ?

Comment: when i alert data length. it returns 1